# Align 2 cards in DIV vertically materialize CSS

Tags: css, datatable, materialize

I have the following form and table that are side by side in 2 columns as shown here:

[image]

This form/table is based on datatable + materialize CSS.

I would like to have the Form and table in a div an make sure that bottom of table and form are always aligned.

I searched around without any solution.

Here goes my code:

```
<div class="divider"></div>
              <!--Basic Form-->
              <div id="basic-form" class="section">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
                    <div class="card-panel">
                      <h4 class="header2">Add or Modify</h4>
                      <div class="row">
                        <form class="col s12">
                          <div class="row">


                            <div class="input-field col s2">
                              <input type="number" id="id" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Id" />
                              <label for="id">Id</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-field col s10">
                              <?php 
                        //// function populate ($sql, $class,$name, $id, $title, $value,$option)

                             echo populate ("SELECT * FROM product_family order by product_type_id ASC","form-control","nm","nm","Select Product", "product_family", "product_family");?>
                              <label for="nm">Product</label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                              <input type="number" step=".01" placeholder="0.00" id="em" name="em" class="form-control" />
                              <label for="em">Win</label>
                            </div>


                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                               <input type="number" step=".01" id="hp" name="hp" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00"/>
                              <label for="message">Drop</label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                              <?php 
                        //// function populate ($sql, $class,$name, $id, $title, $value,$option)

                             echo populate ("SELECT * FROM currency order by id ASC","form-control","ad","ad","Select Currency", "currency", "currency");?>
                              <label for="ad">Currency</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="input-field col s12">

                                 <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveData()">Save</button>
                                 <button type="button" id="update" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="updateData()">Update</button>

                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Form with placeholder -->
                  <div class="col s12 m8 l8">
                    <div class="card-panel">
                      <h4 class="header2">Products In DB</h4>
                      <div class="row">
                            <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th width="20">ID</th>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Win</th>
                            <th>Drop</th>
                            <th width="100">Currency</th>
                            <th width="100">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the css code which will help to solve the issue::

```
.section .row {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    word-break: break-word;
}


.section .card-panel {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome Renaud. It was great to help you